# Does RabbitMQ when persisting messages use the native IOBuffer or does it write directly to disk?

Tags: rabbitmq

When we are using persistent queues and persistent messages in rabbitmq does the message go to the IOBuffer of the native operating system or does it get written to disk immediately.Considering the fact that RabbitMQ is running on CentOS 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ fsyincs to disk every 200ms give or take.

If you need to have guarantees about this, then it's better to use Publisher Confirms: https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

The broker will confirm to the publisher once the message got fsync'ed.

Otherwise you could use transactions, see the `Tx` AMQP class in your library.